# This is from a Python book, the code is throwing errors and should do so

Tags: python, function

I feel like I'm going mad - I'm learning Python and got this code from Al Sweigart's Automate the Boring Stuff.

```
def isPhoneNumber(text):
    if len(text) !=12:
        return False
    for i in range(0, 3):
        if not text[i].isdecimal():
            return False
    if text[3] != '-':
        return False
    for i in range(4, 7):
        if not text[i].isdecimal():
            return False
    if text[7] != '-':
        return False
    for i in range(8, 12):
        if not text[i].isdecimal():
            return False
    return True

print(isPhoneNumber("192-343-2345"))
```

The result should, and does return an error because the String Object has no isDecimal function. I've tried casting the input to an int and String where necessary but it doesn't solve any problems. I'm not copying the code wrong, so I'm not sure what's going on?

Comment: If the function *should* raise an error and *does* raise an error, what's the problem?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Did you mean `isdigit`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works fine on Python 3.

You are correct in saying string object has no isdecimal function in Python 2.

It will work if you use `isdigit` in Python 2.

```
def isPhoneNumber(text):
    if len(text) !=12:
        return False
    for i in range(0, 3):
        if not text[i].isdigit():
            return False
    if text[3] != '-':
        return False
    for i in range(4, 7):
        if not text[i].isdigit():
            return False
    if text[7] != '-':
        return False
    for i in range(8, 12):
        if not text[i].isdigit():
            return False
    return True

print(isPhoneNumber("192-343-2345"))
```